# zoom-in(increase) zoom-out(decrease) font using jquery css

Tags: jquery, css

I want to implement zoom-in(increase) zoom-out(decrease) font using jquery and css

I tried lots of plugin but its not accurate,
Have a look here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $ = jQuery
var section = '#contents *';
var originalFontSize = $(section).css('font-size');  
function resetFont(){
    $(section).css('font-size', originalFontSize);
}
function increaseFont() {
    $(section).each(function(idx, el){
        var currentFontSize = $(this).css('font-size'),
            currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10),
            newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum * 1.2;
        $(this).css('font-size', newFontSize);              
    });
}
function decreaseFont(){

    $(section).each(function(idx, el){
        var currentFontSize = $(this).css('font-size');


        var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
        var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*0.8;

        $(this).css('font-size', newFontSize);        
   });
}
</script>

<div id='contents'>
<div>
Any text here
</div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='zoom' onclick='increaseFont()' />
<input type='button' value='zoom out' onclick='decreaseFont()' />
```

**here zoom in once and zoom out once,and see its not back to normal size**

Working Fiddle : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s4suryapal/NrLmT/3)

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: when i click on zoomin it works,but when i click on zoom out it also works but it does not give proper output as before click on "zoom out"

Comment: it is working just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/EnZ78/

Comment: btw: the selector should be `var section = '#contents'`. why the "*" ? Apart from other problems. but still, the code works.

Comment: here zoom in once and zoom out once,and see its not back to normal size

Comment: that is a different question. just take some time to check this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/EnZ78/1/

Comment: Decreasing a value by a certain percentage, and increasing the same percentage on that decreased value does not give the original value. In this case multiplying with 1.2 and afterwards multiplying with 0.8 does not give the original value. (you can check this: 1 * 1.2 * 0.8 = 0.96). A solution would be to do the increase by dividing by 0.8 (which is the equivalent of multiplying with 1.25)

Comment: @s4suryapal your math is wrong.

Comment: @Me.Name please can you update in fiddle for me.

Comment: If you want to increase by 20% and then decrease by that original 20% you should calculate and store the value somewhere at the start. Then just add and subtract that fixed value.  Or you could increase by `currentFont / 5` and then decrease by `currentFont / 6`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, increasing with a percentage, and decreasing the changed value with the same percentage does not give the original value. Best is to keep one factor constant, and either multiply or divide by it (where dividing is the same as multiplying with 1/factor)

Further, the code uses an each for what now is a single element, so I assumed in my example, that you wanted to increase child elements individually. 
Getting the current font size is centralized, where the originalValue is kept at the same time per element.

(At my current location I can't use jsfiddle, so I used jsbin instead:)

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/gerixolo/16/edit)**

```
var section ;
var factor = 0.8;

function getFontSize(el)
{
    var fs = $(el).css('font-size');    
    if(!el.originalFontSize)el.originalFontSize =fs; //set dynamic property for later reset  
    return  parseFloat(fs);  
}

function setFontSize(fact){
    if(section==null)
       section = $('#contents').find('*')       
       .filter(
         function(){return  $(this).clone()
            .children()
            .remove()
            .end()
            .text().trim().length > 0;
            }); //filter -> exclude all elements without text

    section.each(function(){  
      var newsize = fact ? getFontSize(this) * fact : this.originalFontSize;
      if(newsize) $(this).css('font-size', newsize );      
    }); 
}

function resetFont(){
    setFontSize();
}
function increaseFont() {
    setFontSize(1 / factor);
}
function decreaseFont(){
    setFontSize(factor);
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply,but there is a problem,it does not increase the size of font,it adds space between contents.

Comment: Can you clariy what you mean with it does not increase the size of the font? It does not increase at all, or not in the expected way? Just tested it in firefox/safari and IE, and it seems to work normally

Comment: Hey, this is my fiddle with my content can you please check : http://jsfiddle.net/s4suryapal/ZDm3X/

Comment: Here i have put your code, but its not works,it only add space...please check and help, thanks for reply

Comment: That's because the demo only traverses the immediate line of children, and the elements without text are increased as well. (hence the apparent added space, those are actually elements whose font is increased). To recursively set all elements, we can use `$('#contents').find('*')` instead of children(). Using your html input, please see the updated demo (http://jsbin.com/gerixolo/7/edit).

Comment: hey,thanks for reply but there is a still problem,please note scroll before and after click on 'increase' and 'decrease'. Once click on increase and after click on 'decrease' it not comes in normal. Please check.

Comment: Do you have that behaviour in the jsbin demo? I can't test jsfiddle here, but in the jsbin the scroll behaves as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54033/discussion-between-s4suryapal-and-me-name).